# Show that $\int_0^\infty P(Y < -y)dy = -\int_{-\infty}^0 x f_Y(x)dx$

Tags: probability, integration, multiple-integral

I am trying to understand why $\int_0^\infty P(Y < -y)dy = -\int_{-\infty}^0 x f_Y(x)dx$

My book (Ross) gives a solution where too many steps are skipped for me to follow.

Comment: Where in the book is it (which chapter/problem)?

Comment: Do you understand the corresponding result for $\int_0^\infty P(X>y)dy$?

Comment: @MPW In the 9th edition, it is Ch. 6, theoretical exercise 2.

Comment: @kimchilover No, but I assume it is solved in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

$P(Y<x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_Y(t)dt$. Hence, using integration by parts,
\begin{align}
-\int_{-\infty}^0 x f_Y(x)\,dx=-\left(x\int_{-\infty}^x f_Y(t)dt\right)\Big|_{-\infty}^0+\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^x f_Y(t)\,dt\,dx.
\end{align}
The first term vanishes and the second term becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^0 P(Y<x)\,dx.
\end{align}
Let $y=-x$.

Comment: Every random variable does not necessarily have probability density function.